# Is there a way to remove specific lines from web.config file using azure pipelines?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on project dotnet framework 4.8.
I want to remove some specific lines from my web.config while copying the file to the artifact using azure pipelines.
Below the CopyFiles task:

```
`- task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy web config into the Package
    condition: eq(variables.generateConfigs, true)
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(ReleasesPath.SourceFolderName)'
      Contents: |
        Web.config
      TargetFolder: '$(CopyPath.TragetFolderName)'
      CleanTargetFolder: false
      preserveTimestamp: true`
```

Content of my Web.config :

```
`<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
     <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="Contract1"/>-->
 </service>
<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
     <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="Contract2"/>-->
 </service>`
```

**The Goal:**
Remove all lines with comments.

Expected:

```
`<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
 </service>
<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
 </service>`
```

Comment: What is the OS of your build agent? Is it Linux or Windows?

Comment: It is Windows 10.

Comment: Is it Microsoft hosted or Self hosted?

Comment: It is MS hosted.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if there are built-in tools for this. But you can run PowerShell script to do this for you before you copy file.

```
- powershell: |
     $path = "web.config"
     Get-Content $path | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "^\s*<!--" } | Set-Content $path
```